# How can I use both Realm.io and Dagger (or any multiple dependencies that need annotation processing)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger, realm

I'm trying to use both [Realm.io](http://realm.io/) and [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) in my android app, but I seem to be getting conflict issues with the `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` file.

I've tried adding the following to my build.gradle file:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}
```

and also tried it with `exclude`, but I get errors like the annotation processors aren't being run in either project.

The error I keep running into is the standard `Module adapter for class could not be loaded.`.

What I think is happening is that since both AnnotationProcessors aren't being kept, the processors of one or the other package won't happen, but I could be way off.

Comment: What dagger version are you using?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DenisZinkovskiy just answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AnnotationProcessors should not be in your `compile` dependency scope, they should either be in `provided` or, if you use [android-apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt), `apt`.

It doesn't look like Realm separates out their annotation processor like they should, so that one will need to stay in your compile classpath, but the dagger compiler can move to provided.

This would end up looking something like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.1'
```

The provided (or apt) scope makes the dependencies available to your compiler, but doesn't include them in the final product, which they aren't needed for. The conflict you're running into is in the dex process, but in those scopes these classes will never get that far.

This also has the added benefit of trimming down the size of your final APK.